# Error looping through nested Json Object Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a return of json data from an api and want to output some of it using Blade.

```
 9 => {#670 ▼
    +"id": 10300
    +"name": "Fallout 3: Mothership Zeta"
    +"slug": "fallout-3-mothership-zeta"
    +"url": "https://www.igdb.com/games/fallout-3-mothership-zeta"
    +"created_at": 1431649834920
    +"updated_at": 1532126985619
    +"summary": "Defy hostile alien abductors and fight your way off of the massive Mothership Zeta, orbiting Earth miles above the Capital Wasteland. Mothership Zeta takes Fall ▶"
    +"collection": 3
    +"rating": 77.763623864376
    +"popularity": 1.3333333333333
    +"total_rating": 77.763623864376
    +"total_rating_count": 29
    +"rating_count": 29
    +"game": 15
    +"games": array:10 [▶]
    +"tags": array:4 [▶]
    +"developers": array:1 [▶]
    +"publishers": array:1 [▶]
    +"category": 1
    +"player_perspectives": array:1 [▶]
    +"game_modes": array:1 [▶]
    +"themes": array:1 [▶]
    +"genres": array:2 [▶]
    +"first_release_date": 1249257600000
    +"platforms": array:3 [▶]
    +"release_dates": array:3 [▶]
    +"screenshots": array:7 [▶]
    +"cover": {#681 ▼
      +"url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/btawsi7cbgcmqlw67tpn.jpg"
      +"cloudinary_id": "btawsi7cbgcmqlw67tpn"
      +"width": 1061
      +"height": 1158
    }
  }
```

The bit I wish to get is the cover URL I have tried and loop through all the json data to which 10 items like the above is returned

```
   @foreach ($game as $games)
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <img src="" alt="">
                      <p>{{ $games->name}}</p>
                      @foreach ($games->cover as $cover)
                          <p>{{$cover['url']}}</p>
                      @endforeach
                  </div>
              @endforeach
```

currently, this is what I have in my loop and Im getting this error

Illegal string offset 'url'

Comment: I can see this is the 10th element of a larger array, `$arr[9]`. Are you trying to access only this or you intend to access other elements of the array?

Comment: Just this and the name and ID

Comment: Which error do you get when doing this? Or, if no error, what happens?

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$cover that the error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ $arr[9]->id }}
{{ $arr[9]->name }}
{{ $arr[9]->cover->url }}
```

Note, I am assuming that the name of the larger array of which this is the 10th element is `$arr`. Replace that name with the one in your code.

Comment: But im doing a for each loop and looping through each one,

Comment: So if I want to get just one this works fine but looping through all 10 objects is an issue

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, change `$games` to `$game`:

```
@foreach($games as $game)
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <p>{{$game->name}}</p>
        <p>{{$game->cover->url}}</p> 
    </div>
@endforeach
```